# Git repository with working tree at root of filesystem, cannot add/track anything within the root folder of the repository

Tags: linux, git

I have a repository that I use to track changes in configuration files all over my filesystem. The repository is located at `/root/configtracker`.

##### Edit #=====================================================#

Here is how I created the repository:

```
> cd /root/configtracker
> git --git-dir=.git --work-tree=/ init
```

##### END Edit #=================================================#

To do so, I have this line in my git config:

```
> cat /root/configtracker/.git/config
...
[core]
worktree = /
...
```

I can perfectly `git add` files from anywhere in my filesystem (e.g. `/etc/ssh/...` `/home/user/...`, `/var/named/...`, etc...), **except for files in the actual repository folder, i.e. `/root/configtracker/`**.

Any file from this directory I try to add for commit silently fails without any error message:

```
> cd /root/configtracker
> ls
test
> cat test
hello
> git add test
> git diff --staged
>
```

Nothing is added.

Even with this:

```
> git add -f test
> git diff --staged
>
```

Still nothing is added. Both cases were also checked with `git status`, which doesn't show the file as staged.

I have verified, and don't have any `.gitignore` file in `/`, nor in `/root/` nor in `/root/configtracker/`, nor do I have anything in `/root/configtracker/.git/info/exclude`.

I have tried every trail I found online, but nothing helped me.

Comment: By actual repository folder you mean the folder you've cloned your repository to?

Comment: @mashuptwice I have completed my post with the exact commands I used to initialize the repository :). I haven't cloned it from anywhere, I created it in my local filesystem.

Comment: So you are tracking the files in `/` but you've initialized the repo in `/root/configtracker/`? I'm not sure if git is supposed to work like that. You might want to initialize the repo directly in `/` instead, but set only the `.git` folder to be in `/root/configtracker/.git` as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/916922). I could imagine that with your setup there is some kind of weird cycle happening when trying to add a file.

Comment: The way I have my config tracking setup is via initializing directly in the directory I want to track and adding a .gitignore which excludes all files by default. Works like a charm and I don't have any problems with adding files. Only inconvenience is that I have to add files by running `echo '!*filename' >> .gitignote`.